# Total label above stacked bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a stacked bar chart, with labels for each stacked bar and a total label above the bar.

How am I supposed to solve this?

See example code here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(19)
df <- data.frame(class = rep(c("Math", "History", "Language"), 5),
                 task = rep(c("Reading", "Lecture", "Exercises", "Seminar", "Exam"), 3),
                 time = sample(1:6, size = 15, replace = TRUE))

total <- df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    summarise(time_total = sum(time))

# Plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = class, y = time, fill = task)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label = time), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), colour = "white") +
    geom_text(aes(x = class, y = time_total + .5, label = time_total), data = total)
```

This codes generates this error for me:
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'task' not found

Can't I use several data sources for my plot? Or how am I supposed to get a total label as well?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ggplot() +
geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = class, y = time, fill = task), stat = "identity") +
geom_text(data = df, aes(x = class, y = time, label = time), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), colour = "white") +
geom_text(aes(x = class, y = time_total + .5, label = time_total), data = total)
```

Comment: This codes works only if I order the data as according to PoGibas code above. But it's a nicer way of expressing the data source for each object like this. Thanks!